# How to use 'overlayDir' directive in mat-select?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to style mat-select-panel based on its overLay position,so mat-select provides a `overlayDir: CdkConnectedOverlay` property.

And `CdkConnectedOverlay` provides property `@Output()
positionChange: EventEmitter<ConnectedOverlayPositionChange>` but I can't seem to work it out.

Heres the doc's link: https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
      <mat-select disableOptionCentering panelClass="select-panel-class" overlayDir (attach)="test($event)" (backdropClick)="test($event)" (positionChange)="test($event)">
        <mat-option value="food.value1">
          value1
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="food.value2">
          value2
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option value="food.value3">
          value3
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>

----------------ts-----------------

 test(evt){
    console.log(evt)
  }
```

It should console log the 'backdropClick' ,'attach' and  'positionChange' events but its not displaying anything nor it is showing any errors.
Am I using it correctly? If not please explain how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Angular Material's documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api), `overlayDir` is not a directive but a property inside the `mat-select` component. So you should get `mat-select` component using the ViewChild decorator, then get the overlayDir property, and finally subscribe to the `backdropClick` event emitter. Please see this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-overlaydir-from-mat-select?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Lopez: Yes that is working but the doc is really confusing and in Will Howell's comment (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5252#issuecomment-309832671) ,he said it stands for directive so again I'm more confused.And I'm still not clear why they mentioned it in docs if we have to use it with the help of ViewChild.

Comment: I think he meant that the property name `overlayDir` stands for overlay directive. So that property is a reference to the overlay directive, but is not a directive by itself.

Comment: Can we add `backdropClass` to `CdkConnectedOverlay` using this? If yes how?

Comment: Yes you can do it using:

`this.selectComponent.overlayDir.backdropClass = "myCustomBackdropClass";`

But you will have to include the styles for that class in your styles.css file, if you include them on the component's style file, Angular CSS shadowing and encapsulation logic would avoid them to apply to the child directive. I have updated the stackblitz example to include this.